# How to I scroll to a set distance above/below an element with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a link shown below, which when clicked on, scrolls the user down to the #contactHeader element. What I want to do is scroll to 200px ABOVE the #contactHeader, rather than directly to it. Is there any way I can add rule which implements a -200px check so that it scrolls to 200px above the element?

```
<li><a id="scrollToContact" href="#">&bull;</a></li>

$("#scrollToContact").click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#contactHeader").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be a simple `scrollTop: $("#contactHeader").offset().top - 200` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `offset().top` property returns you an integer, so you can just subtract from it to scroll to a higher position in the page:

```
$("#scrollToContact").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#contactHeader").offset().top - 200
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `- 200` to the end of your `scrollTop` line.

```
$("#scrollToContact").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#contactHeader").offset().top - 200
        // Here -----------------------------------^^^^^^
    }, 1000);
});
```

Or if the header may be within 200px of the top of the page, you may want to throw `Math.max` in there:

```
$("#scrollToContact").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: Math.max(0, $("#contactHeader").offset().top - 200)
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollTop: $("#contactHeader").offset().top -200
```

Comment: Then just skip the parseInt, didn't remember if it was needed or not. Better safe than sorry :)